# How to join procedure data and table data in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have big data ‍and The first query is too big. 
So I make a procedure from the first query. I need procedure (data) join another table join.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE sales_pro()
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM sales;
END;


select * from sales
where sales.rep_id= sales_pro.rep_id

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `reps` (
  `rep_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rep_name` TEXT(50) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO `reps` (`rep_id`, `rep_name`) VALUES
(1, 'John'),
(2, 'Sally'),
(3, 'Joe'),
(4, 'Bob');


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sales` (
  `prod_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rep_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sale_date` DATE NOT NULL,
  `quantity` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`prod_id`,`rep_id`,`sale_date`),
  KEY `rep_id` (`rep_id`)
);


INSERT INTO `sales` (`prod_id`, `rep_id`, `sale_date`, `quantity`) VALUES
(1, 1, '2013-05-16', 20);
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible to join with the results of a procedure.

Comment: Use a view instead of a procedure.

Comment: Correct, you can't SELECT from a procedure in MySQL. For what it's worth, I've used a different brand of RDBMS that does allow this -- InterBase, which was forked to the open-source database Firebird.

Comment: What does the `reps` table have to do with this question?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? It seems you have performance issues you are trying to circumvent?

Comment: I make pivot table but my first query is very long and have many dynamic parameter. I need to make procedure from  first query. First query results join to another table to make pivot table report (row to column)

Answer (score 1):

You can't join with a procedure, but you can do it with a view, which can be treated like a table (although there are some restrictions).

```
CREATE VIEW sales_view AS
SELECT * FROM sales;

SELECT *
FROM sales AS s
JOIN sales_view AS sv ON s.rep_id = sv.rep_id
```

You can't pass parameters to a view, but you can access columns in the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT *
FROM sales AS s
JOIN sales_view AS sv ON s.rep_id = sv.rep_id
WHERE sv.quantity > 10;
```

Comment: How to pass few parameter in view

Comment: You can't pass parameters to a view.

Comment: The closest thing is to use a WHERE clause to restrict the rows you select from a view.

Comment: but I need to pass parameter in my procedure please exam to procedure.

Comment: The procedure in the question doesn't have any parameters.